# Edit Qt Qapp style setting to create dark mode

Tags: c++, qt, qapplication

Just found some awesome free (speech) software to speak to some lab equipment. The background is very white though and I would like to put it in to dark mode. I know nothing about C++. In main.ccp I found this `qApp->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));` couldn't see any hex or rgb values that weren't tied to buttons, so i'm wondering if "Fusion" describes the background colour, and if so is there something I can replace it with to create a dark version of this software?

Comment: Are you building the app from source code yourself? Or just trying to configure a prebuilt binary?

Comment: Some quick web searching reveals [a description of the function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylefactory.html) and [a description of what "fusion" is](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qtquickcontrols2-fusion.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Qt 5 dark Fusion theme available for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035767/is-the-qt-5-dark-fusion-theme-available-for-windows)

Comment: I know literally nothing about C++, i dont know what Qt is, the program is already written i just want to modify it to make the background dark. I'm running Ubuntu. So i was hoping to find a hex code or rgb value for the background, but i cant, I did find the line of code above, and was wondering if its as easy as changing "Fusion" to "Dark" or "Fancy Dark Style" or whatever. I did the quick web search and found both the sites you gave, I know nothing about C++ they didn't help much.

Comment: The problem is even if you changed that line to something that made it dark, C++ is a compiled language, not interpreted. It's not like an HTML file where you can just edit it and reload it in your browser. You would have to rebuild the application. And that requires build tools like a compiler, as well as libraries like Qt, etc. It's not always an easy process if you have never done it before.

Comment: @dogfood If you know nothing of Qt or C++ then you cannot change the style to dark. You should find someone who knows C++ or you should learn it yourself or you just keep using it in light mode but turn down the brighness of your monitor. Sorry, these are your only options.